# Confusion with PHP session_regenerate_id

Tags: php

Struggling with whether or not I have an issue with `session_regenerate_id` in regards to some securing of sessions I am doing.

The code I am working on is pretty similar to a [user post](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php#87905) on php.net, but I have simplified it down for this question and is as follows:

```
ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files');
session_save_path(dirname(__FILE__).'/tmp');

session_start();

$_SESSION['Test'] = "info";
$_SESSION['Test2'] = "more info";

$orig = session_id();

session_regenerate_id();

echo "Original session is ".$orig."<br>";
echo "Regen session is ".session_id()."<br>";
```

This outputs to the screen

> Original session is o9t1rhb2o9affn1ljisic1tas1
>   Regen session is gu9pkhi3loklr02r23m8lkvoh4

The contents of o9t1rhb2o9affn1ljisic1tas1 is

> 

The contents of gu9pkhi3loklr02r23m8lkvoh4 is

> Test|s:4:"info";Test2|s:9:"more info";

As you can see only the new session contains any data, the original one is empty. I was expecting both to contain the same data.

Am I missing something here or is this correct behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

[Read The Manual](http://php.net/session_regenerate_id):

> session_regenerate_id() will **replace** the current session id with a new
>   one, and keep the current session information.

```
session_regenerate_id(true); // Delete old session (default)

session_regenerate_id(false); // Keep old session
```

Comment: I understand that the session id is replaced and the boolean dictates whether the old session is deleted or not. The link i included shows someone using false to keep two sessions going, i'm saying that this isn't working for me as the first session loses it's data

Comment: @neilwatson it's not working because TRUE is the default. The link you posted uses FALSE. When you want the same behaviour, use FALSE.

Comment: Unfortunately we may have to agree to disagree on the default behaviour of the function as a [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/precise_session_management) on php.net and [this](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=noi76uKOJ5wC&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=session_regenerate_id+default+false&source=bl&ots=GgkhDWwM-j&sig=ryOA9_n3etYGiLITsTB91fG061Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBWoVChMImO72vNzLxwIVhmnbCh2cOwZh#v=onepage&q=session_regenerate_id%20default%20false&f=false) reference book say the default is FALSE

Comment: You are right, sorry, my fault!! I have found a problem in your script. You cannot change the session after your first echo, because the headers are already sent then. Please provide a small script to show and verify the problem you encounter.

Comment: Dan I have altered my original post to move the echo and to show the results, hope that helps.